# MariaDB 10.4 random performance degradation

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mariadb-10.4

I have a server with such parameters:

- OS: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS x86_64
- Host: X11DPi-N(T)
- Kernel: 4.15.0-112-generic
- CPU: Intel Xeon Silver 4214 (48) @ 2.201GHz
- GPU: ASPEED Technology, Inc. ASPEED Graphics Family
- Memory: 18552MiB / 96336MiB
- SSD SAMSUNG MZQLB960HAJR-00007 894.3G x 2

With installed `5.5.5-10.4.12-MariaDB-1:10.4.12+maria~bionic`. On this screenshot shown a standard DB load:

[image]

So I have around 400-500 selects per second (mostly from not so large table with 500k records), 100-190 updates per second, and around 50-150 simultaneous connections.

My problem is: sometimes, for no apparent reason, the server has 2000-3000 open connections/processes. According to `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` they are standard SQL requests but with 'Sending data' state and with 400-500 seconds of runtime. Of course, at this time the server freezes and cannot function normally. I said "for no apparent reason" because at this time I do not see any increase in users number or an increase in activity on the website. In addition, restarting the MariaDB service or a complete reboot of the server helps to get out of this situation, but not always: sometimes even after rebooting I almost instantly get the same 2000-3000 frozen processes.

Has anyone encountered similar database behavior? I would be grateful for any ideas.

**UPD:**

1. All of my SELECTs calls only one table (~500k records, without `JOIN` and/or subqueries), and mostly of them have `LIMIT 1`, so not so large amount of data.
2. Error log shown a lot of records like this: `2020-08-26 22:12:35  787380 [Warning] Aborted connection 787380 to db: ... (Got timeout reading communication packets)`
3. `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` is 50 (default)
4. Slow query log does not shown something unusual
5. My `optimizer_switch` settings: `index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on,index_merge_sort_intersection=off,engine_condition_pushdown=off,index_condition_pushdown=on,derived_merge=on,derived_with_keys=on,firstmatch=on,loosescan=on,materialization=on,in_to_exists=on,semijoin=on,partial_match_rowid_merge=on,partial_match_table_scan=on,subquery_cache=on,mrr=off,mrr_cost_based=off,mrr_sort_keys=off,outer_join_with_cache=on,semijoin_with_cache=on,join_cache_incremental=on,join_cache_hashed=on,join_cache_bka=on,optimize_join_buffer_size=on,table_elimination=on,extended_keys=on,exists_to_in=on,orderby_uses_equalities=on,condition_pushdown_for_derived=on,split_materialized=on,condition_pushdown_for_subquery=on,rowid_filter=on,condition_pushdown_from_having=on`

Comment: Use the slowlog to find some naughty queries:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog

Comment: This log in the error log means the database is killing some connection. It could be a problem on your web server side, or in the network. Can you show some queries, and some query plan using `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` ?

Comment: Can you also add the _Client Connections (Total)_ graph when the problem is happening : to check if it is a long time running connection leak, or if your problem happens in a short period of time ? The same screenshot during a crash, with all graphs could be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution turned out to be quite simple: after studying the MariaDB  documentation (especially this article https://mariadb.com/kb/en/thread-pool-in-mariadb/) I added the following to `my.cnf` and the problem is gone

```
thread_handling=pool-of-threads
thread_pool_size=48 
#48 is a number of CPUs
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a classical case of query optimizer randomly going brain-dead. It's a long standing heisenbug.

When you see the queries piled up, run `SHOW EXPLAIN FOR thread_id` for one of the piled up IDs. See if the query plan is non-senical. If it is, edit the query app-side to include index hints to prevent the query optimizer getting it wrong. If you cannot change the queries, you will have to fiddle with `optimizer_switch` setting until you identify and remove the specific option making the optimizer go crazy.

Comment: Which exactly settings you'd recommend? Right now I have such settings as I indicated in my updated question.

Comment: Impossible to guess, you'll have to look at explain for the slow queries, look and what indexing improvements can be made , and if your indexing is perfect and it still picks the wrong execution plan, bisect your way through optimizer switches until you find disabling which one restores the query optimizer behaviour to picking a sane execution plan. This is the sort of thing you will have to get your hands dirty for. Expect to spend a day or two getting to the bottom of it. Or hire a specialist consultancy to look at it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Anything in the [error log](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/error-log/) ?

If the database freezes, it is most likely a disk issue : could be that the disk is full, mariadb freezes for 1 minute if it cannot write anything , the disk could be full if a temporary table fills it, or an alter on one table, using the copy algorithm does; are you monitoring your disk usage (not in the image, you should)? It could be that the disk I/Os are all used by one query : then all query would still run, but very slowly, so is stuck or just really slow? It could be a lock problem ?

Since query are running for a long time (400-500s), it is most likely not a lock : unless you have changed it, the lock wait timeout is shorter ([at least it is on innodb : 50s](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-system-variables/#innodb_lock_wait_timeout)).

If you know that no `ALTER TABLE` are run, and there are no disk issue ([you might want to check the inodes too](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/57544/119372)), it still could be a lock : `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G` to check.

You said that doing a `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` there are only standard SQL request, so most likely no `ALTER TABLE`.

If you have a poorly written query, a temporary table could fill your disk, so you will need to `EXPLAIN` the queries shown when doing a `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` to analyze this, and rewrite / optimize / limit the size of the resultset of such queries, look for `using temporary` (you can also have a sort on disk sometimes: `using filesort`). The [slow query log](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/slow-query-log-overview/) will tell you if there are queries using the disk (if they are not killed when you restart the server).

If you do not have the time to optimize the queries, and if they are big `SELECT` slowing your whole database, to display information to user (reporting), you can kill the queries taking too long with a script : this should be a last resort (your script killing queries taking too long could write them, so that you will be able to analyze them later on).

Temporary tables filling the disk or using all the I/Os are the only cases where I have seen the database freeze and start again after a reboot. For the cases when the database just freezes again, maybe a user is doing the same query again (and again).

**Edit**

It could be it is not your database the problem, but your web application : the error log message indicates that the database is killing some connection.

The combination of *queries are Sending Data* and *aborted connections* is unusual for me. Usually, aborted connections happens if the web application is not closing the connections, and they are in a *Sleep* state. You could check [everything in this post](https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/05/16/mysql-got-an-error-reading-communication-packet-errors/) :

- check for network issues (firewall)
- check for errors in your web application logs
- check if the `max_allowed_packet` is big enough (if your `SELECT` are returning one row, it should not be a problem)

If there are sleeping queries, then you are not closing the connections properly, and then you reach the `max_connection` limit, and no new connection can happen. Something still is not clear : is the database very slow, or is nothing happening at all ? What is happening on the web server side ?

It could also be that the driver (mariadb client) leaves the connection and the query in a *Sending data* state, and is not fetching the end of the data. If it is buffering the output, and is killed before it actually can (and it does not close the connection either), this could happen. It does not fit with the *LIMIT 1* , but that could explain why there are aborted connections and `SELECT` queries in *Sending data* state. What language is your web application in ? I can think of php *unbuffered query* with php processes crashing to recreate such a situation, but it could be another language specific issue. Anyway, this would be very rare.

Comment: @RedOctober do you have an `ORDER BY` clause and `WHERE` clause ? Can they use the same index ? Can you add the `EXPLAIN` for some of those queries ? to check if it is a `filesort` on disk issue.Is this table an InnoDB table ? if it is a MyIsam table, there is table locks.

Answer (score 0):

So, I've been struggling with "Sending Data" queries that hang with a very high write profile system, and I've found used the above solution as well as reducing the dirty pages threshold and using the `FORCE INDEX (blah)` query directive (due to a MariaDB bug).  In may case, the MariaDB version is in the 10.5.x series, and specifically 10.5.13 right now.  The solution was as follows:

```
# -------------------------------------------------------------------
# Flush as often as possible to increase performance on high
# update tables
# -------------------------------------------------------------------
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm = 0.0001
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct     = 0.0001

# -------------------------------------------------------------------
# Thread handling
# -------------------------------------------------------------------
thread_handling             = pool-of-threads
thread_pool_size            = 112
```

Before the solution, I easily had over 50GB of dirty pages, and now it's averaging around 7-10GB.  Since the system is entirely NVMe, flushing the pages more often does not cause any appreciable increase in lag, but the combination of the two has helped.

**Note:** As previously mentioned, there is currently a Query Optimizer bug with MariaDB where the optimizer will not pick the correct index to run queries.  There are workarounds, but the best one at the moment is to use the `FORCE INDEX (blah)` query directive on your larger queries.  This is the third step that was taken.  In fact, I was just watching a video from the MariaDB Foundation where they advised to always test your queries on the new versions of MariaDB before doing the upgrade.  As a workaround, I'm doing the picking for MariaDB now as often as possible.  Here are the bug reports: [MariaDB Issue MDEV-25480](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-25480?filter=-3) [MariaDB Issue MDEV-25830](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-25830?filter=-3)

**Note:** This system has 56 cores in SMT mode, and I've not seen much benefit from SMT mode at all.  Likely will turn it off at some point.

**Note:** Though you can run `EXPLAIN` on both `UPDATE` and `DELETE` queries, you can not `FORCE INDEX (blah)` on either of them.  So, this bug really needs to be resolved by the MariaDB Foundation.  Would be a nice patch to be able to use `FORCE INDEX (blah)` for those query types though.